AVR Atmega328p - Split data into two port registers
I'm trying to split data into two port registers on an Atmega328p.
because i need to avoid using PD0 and PD1 (using tx and rx on an arduino) and also PB6 and PB7 (connected to oscillator).

so i wanna split a byte into PD2-PD7 and PB0 (yes 7 bits, PB1 being used for a button)
i did some research, and seen that masking could be a good idea.
here's the a test-code i wrote as an example:

//in this test, i want to send 0b01000001 or 0x41 on my outputs. 
//lets say i have leds connected, i will have two edges leds turned ON. 

#define F_CPU 16000000UL

void init_port(void);
void led_data(char data);

int main(void){

  init_port();
  led_data(0x81);
  while(1);
}

void init_port(void){
  volatile char *Reg_DIRD = (volatile char *)0x2A;
  volatile char *Reg_DIRB = (volatile char *)0x24;

  *Reg_DIRD = 0xFF;                          //All pins out from PORTD
  *Reg_DIRB = 0x01;                          //PB0 Output, PB1 input (INT0)(not used here)
}

// function to mask and then split data between the two ports

void led_data(char data){

  volatile char *Reg_OUTB = (volatile char *)0x25;
    volatile char *Reg_OUTD = (volatile char *)0x2B;  
  *Reg_OUTB = ((*Reg_OUTD & 0b00000011) | (data & 0b11111100)); 
  *Reg_OUTD = ((*Reg_OUTB & 0b11111100) | (data & 0b00000011));
}

But it doesn't work. the data is only sent through PORTD. where is my mistake ?

The char type shouldn't be used here since it has implementation-defined signedness and is often signed on many compilers. Meaning that doing things like shifting data into bit 7 is bug. You need to use unsigned char instead. Or if you want to write professional code, as seen for every embedded system out there, use the types from stdint.h.

Given you are using an AVR and most likely AVR-GCC, you have a full list of defines for the various registers which make for clearer code, and also take into account any intricacies in the addressing - the lower 32 registers have two addresses, depending on the instruction used.
You also appear to have muddled up your assignments - you appear to be applying the read-modify-write principle (good), but have transposed the destination register when writing back - the modified Port D value is being written to Port B and vice versa.
You're also writing to 2 bits in PORTB, one of which is your push-button, so you will be modifying the pull-up resistor for that button as a result.
I'm guessing that what you really want is:
void led_data(char data){  
  PORTD = ((PORTD & 0b00000011) | (data & 0b11111100)); 
  PORTB = ((PORTB & 0b11111110) | (data & 0b00000001));
}

Similarly *Reg_DIRB becomes DDRB.

However, you also state that your 'data' value is a 7-bit number. If that is the case, you also need to account for shifting of the value when masking. For example if you want to write to data[6:0] to {PD[7:2],PB[0]}, then you will need to mask and shift as follows:
void led_data(unsigned char data){  
  PORTD = ((PORTD & 0b00000011U) | ((data & 0b01111110U) << 1U)); 
  PORTB = ((PORTB & 0b11111110U) |  (data & 0b00000001U)       );
}

Notice how this takes bits [6:1] (the middle 6) from data, and shifts them up 1 bit to become [7:2] (the upper 6) for Port D.
Then bit [0] (the LSB) from data is placed into bit [0] (LSB) of Port B.

Shifting operands that are signed types is almost always a bug. In this case the bit masks constant need to have u suffix to prevent that. The OP's code is also using the wrong type char, but regardless of that, the left operand of the shift ends up int due to implicit promotion. I'd recommend picking up MISRA C and using a MISRA checker to spot bugs like this.

Also read-modify-write isn't necessarily a sensible thing on GPIO port output registers, particularly not where nothing else but your current code uses the port. I don't know the specifics in this case but many MCUs have a separate register for the current pin status and then reading the register while the port is set as output may result in gibberish, since reads might only be available in input mode.

@Lundin that is for the OP to decide. Given he is not using the full port for the LEDs, other stuff may well be using them, I can only go on what the OP has presented. Reading back the PORTx register on the ATMega's is perfectly acceptable, they use PINx for inputs.

I can't comment on the signed/unsigned nature of data. Atmel Studio uses -funsigned-char by default, so it may or may not be signed. Personally I would use stdint.h types, but stuck with the OPs choice to avoid confusion.

Signed or unsigned constants and data, integer promotion or not, avr-gcc produces the optimal add r18, r18 for the bitshift.

That's the thing, if we get accidental signed arithmetic with potential sign flips or undefined behavior, then the compiler might not be able to optimize the code correctly, or worse the result might change. When writing in C we have to suffer implicit type promotion to 16 bits in this case, but if we keep everything to unsigned types the compiler may be able to optimize it into an 8 bit instruction. And all this subtle crap is one of many reasons why 8 bit MCUs shouldn't be used in the year 2024: it is tricky to write safe & correct C for them due to integer promotion.

@TomCarpenter Yes i know, that is what i usually use. But i discovered some examples that are not using the classic versions. I was curious so i want to try myself. To me it is very interesting. Well yes, i could also learn assembly haha

wow guys, you're giving me so much informations! thank you !! @TomCarpenter for the *Reg_DIRB, and not using classic libraries like DDRB, i just wanted to challenge myself, trying to program without the libraries, as i've seen on some examples, where the programmer were directly pointing to register addresses. I find that interesting

The compiler provided headers already define port direction and port data registers etc for you, so defining them yourself is rather pointless.
And you are doing a write to port B with the value read from port D and vice versa.

ok so what can i do for the ports ?

@gowb0w Correct the statement from (in principle) D = B | x; B = D | x; to B = B | x; D = D | x;. Justme's last sentence is clearly stating the error.

-mmcu=atmega328p gave me different addresses from the avr/io.h than what the OP is using. But then I don't know these parts... maybe I picked the wrong one.

@Lundin There are two address spaces, IO and memory. SFRs for many but not all peripherals are available both in IO and memory address spaces. AVR io.h uses IO space for SFR access whenever possible, while OP's code has to use memory address space for accessing registers. I bet the offset is someting like 32 or 64 between them?

Aha, offset seems to be 0x20=32 indeed. I was thinking it was perhaps something related to zero page but apparently not!

General C programming concerns:

Always use stdint.h. Never use char for anything but strings. (unsigned char would be ok).
Always add u/U suffix to all integer constant to avoid accidental signed arithmetic. Avoid signed numbers in general, unless you actually need negative values in some calculation (kind of rare in embedded bare metal).
Avoid accessing a volatile several times in the same expression. Doing so is actually undefined behavior (though compilers tend to support it in some way).
Never write "magic numbers" all over the code, making it unreadable and forcing the reader to sit with their nose in the MCU manual while reading your code.

General microcontroller programming concerns:

Avoid re-inventing the provided register map unless it is godawful poor (which may or may not be the case).
If you insist on manually defining registers, then have a look at How to access a hardware register from firmware?
int main(void) doesn't make sense in bare metal embedded systems. Return to where? This causes extra bloat on the caller side (in the "CRT"). The most common form used for freestanding systems is void main (void) (compile with -ffreestanding in gcc).


Example how to improve the code, with explanations in comments:
#include <avr/io.h> // whatever the name of the provided register map is
#include <stdint.h>

/* Define everything in advance, instead of "magic numbers" all over the place.
   We might not even need to use all of these but it is flexible if we need to
   re-route pins later on. */

// Note the common trick of (1u<<n)-1 giving us a bit mask with n bits set to 1
#define PORTD_LED_BITS 6u                        // 6 value bits
#define PORTD_LED_MASK ((1u<<PORTD_LED_BITS)-1u) // the appropriate data mask, ie 0x3F
#define PORTD_LED_OFFSET 2u                      // starting at pin 2

#define PORTB_LED_BITS 1u                        // 1 value bit
#define PORTB_LED_MASK ((1u<<PORTB_LED_BITS)-1u) // the appropriate data mask, ie 0x01
#define PORTB_LED_OFFSET 0u                      // starting at pin 0

static void led_data (uint8_t data);

void main (void)
{
  DDRD = (PORTD_LED_MASK << PORTD_LED_OFFSET ); // set pins PTD2 to PTD7 as outputs
  DDRB = (PORTB_LED_MASK << PORTB_LED_OFFSET ); // set pin PTB0 as output
  
  uint8_t data = 0x7F;
  led_data(data);
}

static void led_data (uint8_t data)
{
  // do all calculations in advance, not in the same expression where you access a volatile:

  // only access a volatile in an expression of its own
  uint8_t portd = PORTD; // read to preserve value of other pins
  uint8_t portb = PORTB; // read to preserve value of other pins
  portd &= ~(PORTD_LED_MASK << PORTD_LED_OFFSET); // clear old values for LEDs
  portb &= ~(PORTB_LED_MASK << PORTB_LED_OFFSET); // clear old values for LEDs

  portd |= (uint16_t)(data & PORTD_LED_MASK) << PORTD_LED_OFFSET;

  uint8_t tmp_portb; // calculate new value without worrying about other pins
  tmp_portb = data & (PORTB_LED_MASK << PORTD_LED_BITS); // 1 << 6 = 0x40
  tmp_portb = (uint16_t)tmp_portb >> PORTD_LED_BITS; // shift in position for PORTB
  tmp_portb = (uint16_t)tmp_portb << PORTB_LED_OFFSET; // just in case we want to use some other pin in the future
  portb |= tmp_portb; // preserve value of other pins

  // only access a volatile in an expression of its own
  PORTD = portd;
  PORTB = portb;
}

Generated executable with avr-gcc:
-O3 -std=c23 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -ffreestanding -mmcu=atmega328p https://godbolt.org/z/ErWGef8fd
(Swap out atmega328p for whatever applies in your case)
  ldi r24,lo8(-4)
  out 0xa,r24
  ldi r24,lo8(1)
  out 0x4,r24
  in r25,0xb
  in r24,0x5
  ori r25,lo8(-4)
  ori r24,lo8(1)
  out 0xb,r25
  out 0x5,r24

As we can see this got aggressively optimized down to just I/O register bit banging. Most of the arithmetic was done on integer constant expressions at compile time, so it is simply not present. Neither are the local variables I declared for readability purposes. As we can tell, there's no need to write all arithmetic in some horrible "one-liner" in order to get efficient code.

That example of produced assembler isn't actually enough for a general function - it's been over optimised because you have a single write of a constant (the sbi comes from the LSB of the value always being a 1 for the single use case). A better test would be compiling with a whole loop of incrementing data values to see what it produces.

Furthermore the code will not work as is. |= does not give read-modify-write. If you write 0x7F, then try to write 0x00, you will never clear the bits, so it will always tend towards all outputs being high, regardless of the desired value to be written.

@TomCarpenter But we want it to optimize down to plain addresses and numeric constants. And oops, indeed |= won't work if you need to set these on the fly, which seems quite likely with LEDs. I'll tweak the code.

"But we want it to optimize down to plain addresses and numeric constant" - if you are just writing a constant, sure. But if the function is used more than once to write more than just a single value, then it won't look like what is show, that was my only point there. Wasn't a criticism of the code, just pointing out that the assembler isn't really applicable generally.

@TomCarpenter Yep... the bit set instruction went poof when I modified the code, because with the changes it has to update the whole port.

So, general C programming may not apply to 8-bit MCUs. Avr-libc itself uses "unsigned char" in many headers instead of uint8_t for example. Registers are volatile and you need to access them for read-modify-write operations. Accessing registers link you provided may work for AVRs but like I said earlier it makes little sense to access everything via memory access when  you have avr-libc provided macros to use IO access for more efficient access also at bit level too. Just use avr-libc headers, they use compiler provided for IO, while it maps IO via MMIO it knows what to emit.

... Returning from main returns back to the init code that called main() to begin with. It does not use the return value and goes to infinite loop. Great for doing interrupt-driven programs. It does not bloat at all, it's already there for you.

@Justme That means that the CRT has to generate code to accept a returned int, which in turn means that there will be 2 bytes of your stack space permanently gone for no reason. Furthermore the CRT has to contain code to deal with runaway program counter. This is some Arduino thing; normal microcontrollers don't do this. In fact many CRT are written with a local jump to main rather than a subroutine call just to avoid bloating the stack. But also meaning you wouldn't be able to return because then the stack will get corrupted.

But most importantly int main (void) is a design (from the 1970s) that assumes that you are using Unix and returns a status code to the OS. So unless your AVR is using Unix, this was never meant to be.

@Lundin Your assembly includes no runtime code so it can't copy initialized variables and has no jump to reset vector, no stack pointer init etc. Standard avr-gcc examples use standard int main(void) and crt does not care if you return an int or not, and int is returned in registers, not stack. Oh and in fact modern avr-gcc actually disables interrupts and goes to inifinte loop if you exit main(). Nothing to do with Arduino, except Arduino uses avr-gcc.

@Lundin the return from int main() or void main() for avr-gcc are identical. They both produce simply cli; rjmp .-2. No extra stack usage for the return value, etc. Simply disable interrupts and infinite loop. The expected trace is int main(), using anything else produces warnings unless you use additional compiler flags.

Using the default trace without the freestanding flag also allows you to add your own exit code - e.g. to cleanup and reset if you so wish. These are achieved by adding code to special text sections call .fini1 through .fini9. It also allows you to use .initN sections to add code that happens before any runtime initialisation for things which must be done as soon as possible. Realistically this boils down to there being no "must do" for everything - know your enviroment and work to its pecularities.

@TomCarpenter Except I think int main() originates from "must do". The gcc folks are PC people. Additionally the AVR clique seem to think using C++ for an 8-bitter is a brilliant idea - and as it turns out, C++ has stricter rules for the format of main() than C. So if trying to please both languages with the same compiler port, you'd end up with int main() for that reason alone. Then once you've settled for a certain bad idea you can of course adapt the CRT and calling convention accordingly. Then when the user ports to a different compiler, everything turns to crap, but gcc doesn't care.

Also some bad CRT execute a bunch of really dumb s*** from after int main() has returned, such as atexit or C++ destructors. Can't speak for AVR but I've seen that several times. People designing such CRTs need a gentle reminder that a microcontroller is not a PC.
